# Unexpected response code 403 in android when using NewsApi

Tags: android, android-volley, http-status-code-403

Whenever i am using the **NewsApi** it gives me E/Volley: [593] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Apple&from=2021-04-23&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=1ea1cbe36dfd4fdcb846a6f885593f95 exception but none other apis which I used throws this exception, please help me fix this i am trying to find the solution for the past 3 days.

```
 String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Apple&from=2021-04- 
 23&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=1ea1cbe36dfd4fdcb846a6f885593f95";

 JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
       response -> {
            Log.d("show", "Response came ");
       }, error -> {
          Log.d("show", "No response");
   });
   MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(req);
 }
```